# Soft of skin - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Soft of skin
>
> With many inside
>
> Flexible
>
> And in any size
>
> Play with me
>
> Or just sit and rest
>
> Put me in a firearm
>
> If killing would not be best

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be a

> bean bag.

Soft of skin
With many inside

> This is precisely what a bean bag is: a soft skin enclosing lots of small things.

Flexible
And in any size

> The flexibility is the main point of a beanbag. They come in sizes from "small enough to use in a gun" (see below) to "large enough for multiple people to sit on in comfort".

Play with me
Or just sit and rest

> Smaller ones are sometimes used for throwing-and-catching games. Larger ones are usually used for sitting on.

Put me in a firearm
If killing would not be best

> [Bean-bag round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_bag_round). Though occasionally they do kill people, alas.

Comment: Good job! I guess I made it  too easy...

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Beanbag?

Most of the clues should be fairly obvious.

> Beanbags are soft, filled with pellets and therefore flexible. They can be small (and played with) or large (and sat on).

For the last one, we have

> Bean bag rounds - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_bag_round)

Comment: Well done! I will accept Gareth's answer instead though for a slightly mored detailed explanation